# Call shell script "inline" in another shell script

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables

So the bottom line here is that I am trying to have one go-to script work to set environment variables (let's call it `setenv.sh`) that will be used in subsequent scripts.  In Windows (I know, that is a 4-letter word here...) I can use a batch file to set a environment variable for *after* the batch file is over.  I am looking for that same effect.

However, I have just learned, through perusing the internet, that environment variables set in a script (aka a shell) only persist in child shells, and do not affect the parent shells.  Okay whatever, well now what I want to know is can I run a script *inline* in another script?  By *inline*, I am talking about something analogous to C/C++'s `#include` directive.  I want this because if I can call a script *as if* it were running in the current script, my environment variables would at least persist through the duration of my desired script.

For example, something like this:

```
cat ~/install/setenv.sh | /bin/bash
echo "JBoss home directory is set to $JBOSS_HOME"
```

But I realize even that won't quite work, and I am starting a child shell with a call to `/bin/bash`.  I am fine if I have to call this `setenv.sh` for each script I want it to run inline with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to include env variables, you can set those variables in a file, and then `source` that file in your script.

For example:
in myconfig I could do:

```
#!/bin/bash
EDITOR=emacs
JBOSS_HOME=/path/to/jboss/home
```

then in my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /path/to/myconfig
echo "JBOSS home dir is $JBOSS_HOME"
```

and that would work.

Comment: And a shortcut for `source` is just `.`, as in `. /path/to/myconfig`